# How to apply group change via the dir's setgid bit when moving files with 'mv'?

Tags: linux, permissions, group

```
$ mkdir test
$ chown gtgteq:users test
$ chmod g+s test
$ touch test/a
$ touch b
$ mv b test/
$ ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtgteq users  0 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 gtgteq gtgteq 0 b
```

How to change automatically the group of moving files(`b`)?

Comment: It only applies to newly-created files, and that are `mv` into the directory are unaffected by the setgid setting. if it is a requirement you can `cp` and `rm` the file and can make a function for it to automatically do it.

Comment: that's the setgid bit, sticky also exists, but is different, it's `+t` and prevents non-owners from deleting files

Comment: I tried `cp` but setgid doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I wrote bash function.

```
mvs() {
  local dest
  if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
  if [[ -d $2 ]]; then
    dest="$2/$(basename $1)"
  else
    dest="$2"
  fi
  mv "$1" "$2" || return $?
  chown "$USER":users -R "$dest"
  chmod g+rw -R "$dest"
  find "$dest" -type d -exec chmod g+xs {} ';'
}
```